# gravar dados de um DataGridView no banco de dados

Tags: c#, entity-framework, winforms, visual-studio

bom dia, estou fazendo uma aplicaçao parecido com uma venda, que contem vendas e itens de vendas.
o meu problema e que nao estou conseguindo salvar os itens da venda que se encontra no datagridView, estou usando entity framework, ele so esta salvando so um registro.

```
public void InserirItens()
        {
            ItensToras itens1 = new ItensToras();
           
            try
            {
                if (dtGridItens.Rows.Count > 1)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dtGridItens.Rows.Count -1; i++)
                    {
                        itens1.IdCargas = Convert.ToInt32(dtGridItens.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                        itens1.IdAlce = Convert.ToInt32(dtGridItens.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);

                        context.itensToras.Add(itens1);
                    }
                   
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: deveria instanciar um novo objeto para cada vez que vai inserir um novo, ou seja, dentro do `for` incluir isso `ItensToras itens1 = new ItensToras();`

Comment: Amigo Deus abençoe você, eu consegui graças a Deus muito obrigado mesmo de coração.